# Disable access key function for ribbon (mnemonics)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ribbon

I'm using the "access key" function in my views (by pressing `ALT` + `First char of label` I can "jump" into that field):

[image: WPF view with ALT pressed]

By pressing `ALT` + `m` focus should jump to the "Mail" field.

However I have a ribbon in use and by pressing the `ALT` key, the "ribbon tooltips" are shown:

[image: Ribbon tooltips]

So by pressing `ALT` + `m` focus jumps to the correct field, but the primary focus stays on the ribbon and I'm not able to enter anything to that field without pressing `ESC`. Is there any solution for this behaviour? Disabling those tooltips for the ribbon would be a solution which is okay for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable the shortcuts for the Ribbon. Moreover, it will be a bad programming practice...

Instead, try to specify the parent window handle to the Show or ShowDialog method. Both of them accepts an instance of the [IWin32Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.iwin32window(v=vs.110).aspx) interface